# Flexbox height always 100% also when scrolling

Tags: css, sass, flexbox

I have recently created a layout with flexbox that uses a left navbar and a content-area which has a light gray background color. the page contains an outer wrapper called site-container. Its responsible for containing the navbar, under that there is a page wrapper which contains the sidebar and content area.

It lines out properly but the content doesn't get stretched to 100%. I tried many things. setting the site-container to flex-direction: column with align-items stretch but nothing seems to work. The app contains about 1000 lines of scss so I included the website to have a look. Any help will be much appreciated. Cheers!

Link:
https://teams365-dev.azurewebsites.net/

the "Mijn Teams" and "Teams ontdekken" both have content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing height on `siteContainer` div. Add `height: calc(100vh - 48px);` to you `.siteContainer` class style where `48px` is the height of `navbar__container`.

Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you so much. Can I ask why the the 100vh expands as there is more content to scroll down? I always thought it will stop after reaching the end of the page.